How to use variable inside single quotation and placeholder in Snakemake shell
Here is a simplied rule for my problem
rule test:
    output:
        output_tex = expand("TPA_{region}.tex", region = [0,1]),
    shell:
        """
        for((i=0;i<2;i++));
        do echo '"{output.output_tex['$i']}"';
        done
        """

My expected output is
"TPA_0.tex"
"TPA_1.tex"

Normally, to quote a variable inside single quotation I can use ''$i''. however, with Snakemake shell placeholder, it's ambiguous. I wonder whether this could be done.

did you try adding a backslash? \$i

"My expected output is" ... We need to see your current output. Please edit the body of your question and DON'T reply in comments, except to say, "See updates in question". Good luck.

Use ":q" formatting instruction to force Snakemake to quote the values that contain a space, see docs:
rule test:
    output:
        output_tex = expand("TPA_{region}.tex", region = [0,1]),
    shell:
        """
        for output in {output.output_tex:q};
           do echo "$output";
        done
        """


Thanks for your help. But did you test this rule? I run this rule and the result is AttributeError: 'Namedlist' object has no attribute ''$i'', when formatting the following:

Oops. It's probably worth simplifying the problem a bit to directly iterate over the outputs, see the updated version.

Looks good to me, but you probably need a space before the ; character. If you need the value of $i you can make an explicit counter and increment it as you loop.

Note that the original form of the question can never be made to work, because Snakemake just inserts all the variables into the placeholders within the text of the script before the script is run. There's no way for your shell code to "reach back" to get a specific value from the input list, unless you store the whole input list into a shell list (which is also do-able, but not needed here).
